# FlexBE does but does not connect

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am following the FlexBE tutorials. The problem is I never get the FlexBE app connection. Onboard Status is "disconnected". rosbridge, rosapi, flexbe_onboard are all running. Moreover, I see the message on rosbridge output "Client connected. 1 clients total." FlexBE console does not show any error. And "Connect" button on the Configuration screen is deactivated as if it is already connected. It seems some part of the program believes it is connected but others disagree.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248690/flexbe-does-but-does-not-connect/) by [trgtylcnky](https://answers.ros.org/users/28434/trgtylcnky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-11-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-24**:
I'm not sure the author(s) of FlexBE frequent ROS Answers. You might want to try and post an issue to the FlexBE [issue tracker](https://github.com/team-vigir/flexbe_behavior_engine/issues). Do report back here if/when you receive an answer. Thanks.

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2017-08-14**:
We are following at https://github.com/team-vigir/flexbe_behavior_engine/issues/35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was asked and answered on https://github.com/team-vigir/flexbe_behavior_engine/issues/29 with no follow up from user.

---

Originally posted by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) with karma: 476 on 2017-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1